# Connect two VPN in a row (Cisco Anyconnect)

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I need to connect to 2 VPN which I should connect to with Cisco AnyConnect. The first one gets me the internet connection from so it's essential taht the second connection has to be established thorugh this one. The second is the VPN from my work, which I need to be connected to.

Is there a way to use other software (I'm trying ShrewSoft VPN right now but can't figure out some credentials) since you can't do it with Cisco AnyConnect?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the Windows built-in VPN client? If both connections are created by the built-in client, we are able to dial up the first one automatically when we try to connect to the secondary VPN connection.

Here is the screenshot of my computer:
[image: Two VPN Connections on my computer]

In your case, please try to establish the first connect through Windows built-in VPN client.

Hope this helps.